# Segmentation Fault : 11 in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

so i just update the latest Xcode version. at the 9.4.1, it seems fine. But after i upgrade it to 10, i got an error that says "Segmentation Fault : 11". Here's the log:

> 1. While emitting SIL for 'insertOrUpdateChannel(activity:channel:user:completion:)' at /Users/wmotionmac/Project/Wmotion/WWF Content Manager/WWF Content Manager/Model/Api/Api.swift:273:5
> 2. While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$S19WWF_Content_Manager17DetailActivityApiV21insertOrUpdateChannel8activity7channel4user10completionyAA0E0C_AA0J0CAA4UserCySbctFZ".
>      for 'insertOrUpdateChannel(activity:channel:user:completion:)' at /Users/wmotionmac/Project/Wmotion/WWF Content Manager/WWF Content Manager/Model/Api/Api.swift:273:5
>      error: Segmentation fault: 11

Here's the code for insertOrUpdateChannel

```
//TODO:- Create or Update Channel
static func insertOrUpdateChannel(activity: Activity, channel: Channel, user: User, completion: @escaping(Bool)->()) {
    let url = URL(string: Base.api + "/channelactivitypage?calendarId=\(activity.id)")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    if channel.id.elementsEqual("") {
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
    } else {
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    }
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var tema = [String : Int]()
    var themes = [[String : Int]]()
    var assets = [[String : Any]]()
    let email = ["ID": String(describing: "2c53ea1f-6ebe-e811-a977-000d3aa00fc2"), "Name": String(describing: "TV Broadcast"), "List_EmailListModels": nil]

    for theme in channel.themes {
        if !theme.elementsEqual("") {
            tema = ["Value" : Int(theme)!]
            themes.append(tema)
        } else {
            tema = ["Value" : -1]
            themes.append(tema)
        }
    }

    if channel.digitalAsset.count > 0 {
        for asset in channel.digitalAsset {
            let media = ["ID" : asset.id, SerializationKeys.name : asset.name, SerializationKeys.description : asset.description, SerializationKeys.copyRightCredit : asset.copyRightCredit, SerializationKeys.location : asset.location]
            assets.append(media)
        }
    } else {
        let media = [SerializationKeys.name : "", SerializationKeys.description : "", SerializationKeys.copyRightCredit : "", SerializationKeys.location : ""]
        assets.append(media)
    }

    let parameters = [["ID" : channel.id, SerializationKeys.name : activity.activityName, SerializationKeys.channelType : channel.channelType, SerializationKeys.publish_date : "2018-09-21T01:00:00Z", "Headline" : channel.headline, SerializationKeys.content : channel.content, SerializationKeys.emailSubject : channel.emailSubject, SerializationKeys.emailURL : channel.emailURL, SerializationKeys.mention : channel.mention, "PostLink" : channel.postLink, SerializationKeys.channelMobileId : channel.mobileId, "Hastag" : nil, SerializationKeys.tema : themes, SerializationKeys.emailGroup : [email], "ApprovalStatus" : channel.channelStatus, SerializationKeys.rubric : channel.rubric, "ApprovalNote" : channel.note, "DigitalAsset" : assets, "ApprovalEmployeeId" : user.id, "ApprovalEmployeeLevel" : user.level]] as [[String : Any]]
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if !json["Message"].stringValue.elementsEqual("") {
                completion(false)
            } else {
                 completion(true)
            }
        case .failure(_):
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for DetailActivity

```
DetailActivityApi.insertOrUpdateChannel(activity: self.activity!, channel: channel, user: self.user!) { (isSuccess) in
                            if isSuccess {
                                DetailActivityApi.updateDetailActivity(activity: self.activity!, user: self.user!) { (error) in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        print(error!)
                                        Message.connectionFailed()
                                        Loading.hide()
                                    } else {

                                    }
                                }
                                self.db.deleteChannelData(id: id, completion: { (isSucceed) in
                                    if isSucceed {
                                        if let digitalAsset = data {
                                            self.db.deleteAsset(id: digitalAsset[self.db.ID]) { (_) in

                                            }
                                        }

                                        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                        Message.custom(title: "Submit", body: "Send activity to server", type: .success)
                                    } else {

                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        Loading.hide()
```

Comment: What is at line 273 in the file `/Users/wmotionmac/Project/Wmotion/WWF Content Manager/WWF Content Manager/Model/Api/Api.swift`?

Comment: static func insertOrUpdateChannel(activity: Activity, channel: Channel, user: User, completion: @escaping(Bool)->())

Answer (score 0):

Ok so finally, i find the solution by the help of my friend. there's a bug on my code and after changing, here's the result

```
static func insertOrUpdateChannel(activity: Activity, channel: Channel, user: User, completion: @escaping(Bool)->()) {
    let url = URL(string: Base.api + "/channelactivitypage?calendarId=\(activity.id)")
    var parameters: [[String : Any?]] = []
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    if channel.id.elementsEqual("") {
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
    } else {
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    }
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var tema = [String : Int]()
    var themes = [[String : Int]]()
    var assets = [[String : Any]]()
    let email = ["ID": String(describing: "2c53ea1f-6ebe-e811-a977-000d3aa00fc2"), "Name": String(describing: "TV Broadcast"), "List_EmailListModels": nil]

    for theme in channel.themes {
        if !theme.elementsEqual("") {
            tema = ["Value" : Int(theme)!]
            themes.append(tema)
        } else {
            tema = ["Value" : -1]
            themes.append(tema)
        }
    }

    if channel.digitalAsset.count > 0 {
        for asset in channel.digitalAsset {
            let media = ["ID" : asset.id, SerializationKeys.name : asset.name, SerializationKeys.description : asset.description, SerializationKeys.copyRightCredit : asset.copyRightCredit, SerializationKeys.location : asset.location]
            assets.append(media)
        }
    } else {
        let media = [SerializationKeys.name : "", SerializationKeys.description : "", SerializationKeys.copyRightCredit : "", SerializationKeys.location : ""]
        assets.append(media)
    }
    let params = ["ID" : channel.id, SerializationKeys.name : activity.activityName, SerializationKeys.channelType : channel.channelType, SerializationKeys.publish_date : "2018-09-21T01:00:00Z", "Headline" : channel.headline, SerializationKeys.content : channel.content, SerializationKeys.emailSubject : channel.emailSubject, SerializationKeys.emailURL : channel.emailURL, SerializationKeys.mention : channel.mention, "PostLink" : channel.postLink, SerializationKeys.channelMobileId : channel.mobileId, "Hastag" : nil, SerializationKeys.tema : themes, SerializationKeys.emailGroup : [email], "ApprovalStatus" : channel.channelStatus, SerializationKeys.rubric : channel.rubric, "ApprovalNote" : channel.note, "DigitalAsset" : assets, "ApprovalEmployeeId" : user.id, "ApprovalEmployeeLevel" : user.level] as [String : Any?]

    parameters.append(params)
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if !json["Message"].stringValue.elementsEqual("") {
                completion(false)
            } else {
                 completion(true)
            }
        case .failure(_):
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also, based on my experience, the segmentation error comes from the code itself or the framework